# How to split sales from weekly data to daily without taking weekends into account? (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have this dataset:

```
create table ds
(
dt date,
summ int
);
insert into ds values ('26.02.2013', 312)
insert into ds values ('05.03.2013', 833)
insert into ds values ('12.03.2013', 225)
insert into ds values ('19.03.2013', 453)
insert into ds values ('26.03.2013', 774)
insert into ds values ('02.04.2013', 719)
insert into ds values ('09.04.2013', 136)
insert into ds values ('16.04.2013', 133)
insert into ds values ('23.04.2013', 157)
insert into ds values ('30.04.2013', 850)
insert into ds values ('07.05.2013', 940)
insert into ds values ('14.05.2013', 933)
insert into ds values ('21.05.2013', 422)
insert into ds values ('28.05.2013', 952)
insert into ds values ('04.06.2013', 136)
insert into ds values ('11.06.2013', 701)
;
```

As the title suggests I need to split sales from weekly data to daily. The thing is that there are no sales on weekends, so the number of daily sales on Saturday and Sunday is 0. In that case the simple (week number/7) doesn't actually work. It must be (week number/5), but I don't know how to exclude weeknds from my code. For example, 05.03.2013 - 2 days of this particular week refers to February and 3 of them to March. Then I need to aggregate all sales from all days that refers to a specific month into one number.

The final table should include 2 columns - 1) the sum for each month and 2) month number (from 2 to 6 in this particular example).

Here is my little template where you can see a wanted result (obviously the calculations for each month are not right):

```
drop table if exists #subtable
declare @first_date date = (select top 1 dt from ds)                                                 
declare @mindate date = (select DATEADD(day, -6, @first_date))
declare @maxdate date = (select max(dt) from ds)

;with cte as 
    (
    select @mindate as firstdate
    from ds
    union all 
    select dateadd(day, 1, firstdate) from cte
    where firstdate < @maxdate and firstdate >= @mindate
    )
select distinct *
into #subtable
from cte 
option(maxrecursion 0)
select month(firstdate) as MonthNumber, round(sum(dailysale), 2) as overall_sales
from
    (
    select 
        d.firstdate, dailysale = ds.summ / 7
    from ds
    full join 
    #subtable d on d.firstdate <= ds.dt and d.firstdate >= DATEADD(day, -6, ds.dt)
    ) as newttt
group by month(firstdate);
```

Comment: Date handling differs between different DBMS so you should probably reveal what it is.

Comment: how will you decide the split of the weekly value - is it intended to be even for each day of that week?

Comment: @Randy, yes, you are right

Comment: @Maxdva every single date you listed in your example data is a Tuesday, I'm confused as to what you mean by "without taking weekends into account". Will there be different dates in your table other than Tuesdays? Might I suggest that you provide a more accurate example of the data that will be in your table as well as a sample of what you want the result from your query to be.

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak, I just posted a code with which I came up with. The data above is the all data I have. The thing is that there are no sales on weekends, so the number of daily sales on Saturday and Sunday is 0. In that case the simple (week number/7) doesn't actually work. It must be (week number/5), but I don't know how to exclude weeknds.

Comment: @Maxdva ok, given the data in the table as you provided above, can you please post an example of how you want the result of your query to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this attempt in t-sql to clarify your question. Your sample data is very small, so it's difficult to ascertain how the final aggregation should be handled. Please run this and help us edit for you.

This query assumes there is one day per week in your source table (are they always Tuesdays?) and you want to average that summ over the 5 weekdays.

```
--SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

declare @ds table
(
dt date,
summ int
);
insert into @ds values ('26.02.2013', 312)
insert into @ds values ('05.03.2013', 833)
insert into @ds values ('12.03.2013', 225)
insert into @ds values ('19.03.2013', 453)
insert into @ds values ('26.03.2013', 774)
insert into @ds values ('02.04.2013', 719)
insert into @ds values ('09.04.2013', 136)
insert into @ds values ('16.04.2013', 133)
insert into @ds values ('23.04.2013', 157)
insert into @ds values ('30.04.2013', 850)
insert into @ds values ('07.05.2013', 940)
insert into @ds values ('14.05.2013', 933)
insert into @ds values ('21.05.2013', 422)
insert into @ds values ('28.05.2013', 952)
insert into @ds values ('04.06.2013', 136)
insert into @ds values ('11.06.2013', 701);

    
select  *, 
        datename(dw, s.d) as [Weekday], 
        case when datepart(dw, s.d) not in (1,7) then summ/5. else 0 end as [DailySumm] 
from @ds 
cross
apply (select dateadd(day, -n.n, dt)
        from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6))n(n)
)s(d);
```

This returns a row per day for the *preceding* week of each summ, with the daily average for each weekday:

```
...
2013-02-26 312         2013-02-20 Wednesday                      62.400000
2013-03-05 833         2013-03-05 Tuesday                        166.600000
2013-03-05 833         2013-03-04 Monday                         166.600000
2013-03-05 833         2013-03-03 Sunday                         0.000000
2013-03-05 833         2013-03-02 Saturday                       0.000000
2013-03-05 833         2013-03-01 Friday                         166.600000
2013-03-05 833         2013-02-28 Thursday                       166.600000
2013-03-05 833         2013-02-27 Wednesday                      166.600000
2013-03-12 225         2013-03-12 Tuesday                        45.000000
...
```

Hopefully this helps you describe exactly how you want the weekly/monthly aggregation to be handled. With this dataset, grouping by week or month should be straightforward.

Comment: Yes mate, you are going in the right direction. Although the sales must go backwards. For a better explanation lets go to 05.03.2013:
1) The average for this week must be 166.6 as you posted
2) But the days are not correct: it should be 05.03 = 166.6; 04.03 = 166.6; 03.03 = 0 (as it is a weekend); 02.03 = 0 (same); 01.03 = 166.6; 28.02 and 27.02 = 166.6;

Comment: @Maxdva   I see, yes the preceding week would make more sense. Please see latest update.